# magento ajax variable alert issue

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
if (url) {
    new Ajax.Request(url, 
    {
      method: 'post',
      parameters:{onverifyphone:$('onverifyphone').value},
      onSuccess: function(transport) {
                  var response = "1234";

                 '<?php
session_start();
                  $_session['xyz']=response;?>';

                  alert(<?php echo $_session['xyz'];?>);

                  return true;
                  }
    });
    }
});

Event.observe('verify','click',function(){
     '<?php session_start();?>';
     alert('<?php echo $_session['xyz'];?>');

return true;



});
```

===========================

On first alert is 1234
while on verify button even it shows [object Object]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24yel.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve ? What do you store in the `$_session['xyz']` variable ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Magento

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about the scope when PHP is executed and when JavaScript is executed. After PHP served this site, the JS looks like this:

```
if (url) {
    new Ajax.Request(url, 
    {
      method: 'post',
      parameters:{onverifyphone:$('onverifyphone').value},
      onSuccess: function(transport) {
                  var response = "1234";

                 '';

                  alert(response);

                  return true;
                  }
    });
    }
});

Event.observe('verify','click',function(){
     '';
     alert('response');

return true;

});
```

You will see that this does not make much sense.

Note that this **PHP code** will assign a constant "response", it does not know anything about JavaScript variables:

```
$_session['xyz']=response;
```

(and it also logs an error because there is no `response` constant. But PHP is forgiving about this and uses the string "response")

Since you did not explain what you are trying to do, I cannot offer you a solution, but I hope this answer helps you to understand what is going on.

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with Magento, you should ask the question on StackOverflow - but with more details, what you are doing and why.